# On-premise SQL Server to Azure PostgreSQL replication

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, azure, database-replication

The client has on-premise SQL Server on his side. We want to replicate his database to our PostgreSQL Azure. The replication we want can have maximum 1min delay. ADF is not the option - copying is too frequent.
What tools can we use? We thought about Azure Sync or SymetricDS. Eventually Would SQL Server -> SQL Server be easier to execute? Any suggestions even beyond Azure are much appreciated.

Comment: The normal way of getting data out of SQLServer is using SSIS or a custom process utilising change tracking or change-data-capture. Azure also has an installable module for DataSync processes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database]

Comment: SQL Server -> SQL Server allows the use of Azure DataSync or Replication to achieve your latency restrictions.   Native SQL Server -> PostgreSQL doesn't exist so you would need to make use of a 3rd party replication tool or try adding it as a Linked Server and running your own CDC based process

Comment: Hi @Jaxer, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Hi @JosephXu, you understood the question well. Thank you. I think we are going to use skyvia then but still waiting for my boss to approve.

Comment: Hi@Jaxer. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Martin Cairney said on-prem SQL Server -> Azure PostgreSQL doesn't exist in Azure DataSync, so you would need to make use of offical or a 3rd party replication tool. Azure DataSync only support Azure SQL as the Hub Database.

1. Offical tool, such as Azure data factory. You can set a trigger condition to reduce the frequency of copy activities.
2. 3rd party tool, sunch as [skyvia](https://skyvia.com/data-integration/). You said SymmetricDS maybe not support Azure PostgreSQL, according to its [official doc](https://www.symmetricds.org/about/overview).